# Sending http request in process on exit in node.js

Tags: node.js

I wrote a small library which buffers messages and send them every 10 seconds to an http server.
I wanted to register the exit event for process, and send the remaining messages in the buffer before the process exits. The issue I ran into was that the exit handler must make synchronous calls.

I tried using libraries like "sync" but I end up leaving the process without the http request firing at all.

Any suggestions how to do it?

Comment: maybe a code snippet would help

Comment: I'd suggest a different strategy.  Whatever is currently calling `process.exit()` should instead just notify your app to shutdown (and not call `process.exit()` and then your shutdown routine can send all buffered messages asynchronously and, when done, call `process.exit()`  itself to shutdown.  Because of the way it works, you can't finish normal processing from inside of `process.exit()` - you can only do emergency synchronous things.

Comment: FYI, you could also write your buffer to disk (synchronously) so when you startup again, you can resume asynchronous processing of buffered messages.  This obviously works better in an environment where your server is automatically restarted so the sending can resume soon.